# Plotly not registering "size" array

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Generating several subplots to investigate color palette. The plot (made with Plotly) is a scatter, with colors increasing in tandem with size. The code:

```
fig3 = go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=[2,2,2,2,2], mode="markers", marker={"size": [100,125,150,175,200], "color": [1,2,3,4,5], "sizemin":50}, color_continuous_scale=colors)
```

The colorscale:

```
Colors = [
    "#FFFFEF",
    "#FFCA8C",
    "#FFA05C",
]
```

Obviously there is more than one way to generate this with an array - But what confuses me is why an error is thrown. How should the "size" param be used if not like this?

```
    ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Scatter: 'color'

Did you mean "fill"?
```

Documentation:

Answer (score 0):

There's no parameter as *color_continuous_scale* in Scatter class.

You can use *colorscale* instead in **marker**:

```
fig3 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    mode="markers",
    marker={
        "size": [100, 125, 150, 175, 200],
        "color": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "sizemin": 50,
        "colorscale": Colors, 
    },
)
```